# With iOS 7's view controllers being full screen, is it possible to set a constraint to the very top of the view, not just the nav bar?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

When I align a UILabel to the top, my option is superview but it always uses the nav bar as the reference point. This causes problems when I hide the navigation bar and the constraint adjusts to the fact that there's no longer a nav bar and it causes the label to be pulled higher, which is an unfortunate reaction I don't want to happen (I want it to stay in place).

Is it possible to just say my UILabel should be always, say, 100pt from the top of the full screen view?

Comment: Maybe you can try the "Translucent" option of the navBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Interface Builder, but you can do this easily in code, e.g.:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[label]"
                           options:0
                           metrics:nil
                           views:@{@"label" : self.label}]];
```

**UPDATE**: Previously I've assumed that the label is a subview of the main view. If it isn't then you can use the following constraint:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:self.label
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:self.view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          multiplier:1.0
                          constant:100]];
```

I've tested it and it's working fine.

Comment: Still does the same thing.